# Google sheets api append function to columns out of order

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have the order of data that I want to insert, but I may want to skip a few columns when using google-ads python sdk to insert to the google-sheet.

Is it possible to do this in one shot, or is there a better approach?

```
                                    insertion_ranges = "A1:C1,K1:Z1,AA2"
                                    service.spreadsheets().values().append(
                                        spreadsheetId=spread_sheet_id,
                                        range=insertion_ranges,
                                        valueInputOption=VALUE_INPUT_OPTION,
                                        body=body
                                    ).execute()
```

Comment: Would [`batchUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) be ideal for your setup? Also, could you please add some dummy data for replication purposes?

Comment: Can you provide the sample values for `insertion_ranges = "A1:C1,K1:Z1,AA2"`?